# Ionic 3 Cordova Resource Network Connectivity Error

Tags: android, cordova, build, proxy, ionic3

I want to change my default icon and splash screen, so I replaced my old `icon.png` and `splash.png` files with new ones and ran the below command

`ionic cordova resources android`

It fails and gives the below message

```
√ Collecting resource configuration and source images - done!
√ Filtering out image resources that do not need regeneration - done!
× Uploading source images to prepare for transformations - failed!
[ERROR] Network connectivity error occurred, are you offline?

        If you are behind a firewall and need to configure proxy settings, see:
        https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuring.html#using-a-proxy

        Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND res.ionic.io res.ionic.io:443
            at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
            at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
```

What is causing this issue?

**Note:** I am not behind any firewall or using a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the ionic server is not responding. In that case, you can use an NPM package [cordova-res](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-res) which allows you to generate resources offline. Works for Android as well as iOS.